# How to use a thousand separator in the fractional-part of a number

Tags: python, number-formatting

The number I work with must have 8 digits precision (solved using Decimal) and I would love to print the fractional part with a thousand separator.

I currently use f"{100000.12345678:016_.8f}" that generates "100_000.12345678" but I would like to obtain "100_000.123_456_78" instead

Comment: It's not available, IMHO. Implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly with an f-string format specification. You can do it "manually" though by utilising the built-in *textwrap* module.

```
from textwrap import wrap

def format(n: float, w: int=8) -> str:
    a, b = f"{n:_.{w}f}".split(".")
    return a + "." + "_".join(wrap(b, 3))

print(format(100000.12345678))
```

**Output:**

```
100_000.123_456_78
```